# Serialisation without use ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, serialization

It can possible to serialise an object without used `ObjectOutputStream` ?

Until now i find just this two solution to serialize and object :

```
FileOutputStream fichier = new FileOutputStream("File.ser");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fichier);
stream.writeObject(m);
```

Or

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOutput);
stream.writeObject(m);
```

Comment: @skaffman : when i use `stream.writeObject(m);` and **m** is a great object i have exception :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:282)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.write(ObjectOutputStream.java:1811)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1504)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)

Answer (score 2):

To `serialize` just means to produce a stream of data from an object which, at some later time, can be used to reproduce the same object. Therefore, by definition, yes. You can write any number of alternative serialization mechanisms.

Now, would you want to do this? No, probably not. If you don't like Java's default serialization format, the externalization mechanism gives you the hooks to change it however you'd like.

Comment: another solution to serealize an object without ObjectOutputStream !